# Hide only triggered element, while others has same class

Tags: jquery

I have lots of buttons, After a click on it I want each of them depending on which was clicked - to be hidden.
Right now I've done this, but instead of this:

```
$(".like.1").click(function()
{
$(".like.1").hide();
});
$(".like.2").click(function()
{
$(".like.2").hide();
});
$(".like.3").click(function()
{
$(".like.3").hide();
});
```

Can this be done somehow like this ?

```
$(".like").click(function() 
{
$t(".like").hide(); <--- hide only button which was clicked, while others with same class are not triggered
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".like").click(function() 
{
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having multiple elements to do some functionality of hiding, you can try the below code:

```
$(".like").click(function() {
   hideElement($(this));
});

function hideElement(elmt) {
   $(elmt).hide();
}
```

This make the code more maintainable, in case if you want to perform more other stuff on click of each element.

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as:

```
$(".like").click(function(){
   $(this).hide(); 
});
```

the element will get by this